# How to pass IconData dynamically in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am working on a sample app to learn Flutter. What I want is to display an icon on top of a title. The Category class is responsible to build this widget.

```
class Category extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final IconData icon;

  Category({@required this.title, @required this.icon});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.blue,
        height: 100.0,
        width: 200.0,
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            print('$title was tapped!');
          },
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                Icon(icon, color: Colors.white, size: 10,), // <===== My problem is here
                Text(
                  this.title,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                )
              ],
            )
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I create this widget like this and pass it to ListView.builder.

```
var _categories = [
    Category(title: "Test 1", icon: Icons.airline_seat_flat),
    Category(title: "Test 2", icon: Icons.airline_seat_flat_angled),
    Category(title: "Test 3", icon: Icons.airline_seat_individual_suite),
    Category(title: "Test 4", icon: Icons.airline_seat_legroom_extra)
  ];
```

The looks like this:
[image]

However, if I replace the above line with this line then I see the icon.

```
Icon(Icons.star, color: Colors.white, size: 20,),
```

[image]

So, my question is how I can pass the icon from the outer widget to this widget? Thank you.

Comment: Try passing the Category items with Icons.star, maybe you don't actually have the airline ones

Comment: icons are visible,  even if you pass in list view.

Comment: how you pass icon data to category in ListView.builder? can you import it codes too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
Your code showed in question works well, I only added `ListView.builder` part 
I change icon size to 30 for demo
code snippet

```
child: ListView.builder(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
              itemCount: _categories.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return _categories[index];
              }),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class Category extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final IconData icon;

  Category({@required this.title, @required this.icon});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.blue,
        height: 100.0,
        width: 200.0,
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            print('$title was tapped!');
          },
          child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                  Icon(
                    icon,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    size: 30,
                  ), // <===== My problem is here
                  Text(
                    this.title,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                  )
                ],
              )),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  var _categories = [
    Category(title: "Test 1", icon: Icons.airline_seat_flat),
    Category(title: "Test 2", icon: Icons.airline_seat_flat_angled),
    Category(title: "Test 3", icon: Icons.airline_seat_individual_suite),
    Category(title: "Test 4", icon: Icons.airline_seat_legroom_extra)
  ];

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                  itemCount: _categories.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return _categories[index];
                  }),
            ),
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My build code was like yours except I didn't have padding. That's strange why it didn't work for me.